# Find filenames that contain number

Tags: linux, find, filenames, wildcards

I would like to find file names which contain a number and list them in a range of numbers. For example, in my directory I have:
**

```
Ion_001_rawlib.bam
Ion_002_rawlib.bam
Ion_003_rawlib.bam
Ion_004_rawlib.bam
Ion_005_rawlib.bam
...
Ion_020_rawlib.bam
```

**

and I want to list only Ion filenames from 003 to 005. I tried to do something like that:

```
find -name '*Ion_*[3-5]*rawlib.bam'
```

but it doesn't produce the effect expected. Do you have any idea if it can be performed?
Thanks.

Comment: `ls Ion_*[3-5]*rawlib.bam` should work.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"doesn't produce the effect expected"*? Clearly `*[3-5]*` will match things like 123 - if you need to match **only** 003-005 then be more specific ex. `find -name 'Ion_00[3-5]_rawlib.bam'`

Comment: for example if I write my command line, it outputs me: `Ion_005, Ion_010, Ion_015, Ion_020, Ion_025`, I was expecting `Ion_002,Ion_003,Ion_004,Ion_005`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `zsh` shell, you can do:

```
print -rC1 Ion_<3-5>_rawlib.bam
```

Where `<x-y>` is a glob operator that matches on textual decimal representations of  positive integer numbers within the given range (from `x` to `y`, included).

Recursively:

```
print -rC1 -- **/Ion_<3-5>_rawlib.bam
```

(add `(D)` if you also want to look for those files in hidden folders, or `(N)` if you don't want to consider it an error when there's no matching file).

With `find` implementations that support a `-regex` predicate, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regex '.*/Ion_0*[345]_rawlib\.bam'
```

(matches for file paths that are 0 or more (`*`) bytes (`.` with `LC_ALL=C`) followed by `/Ion_` followed by 0 or more (`*`) `0`s, followed by either one of the `3`, `4` or `5` characters followed by `rawlib.bam`).

Here, it's relatively easy for a 3..5 range, but it would become much more painful for ranges like 78..123 for instance (and you'd run into compatibility issues as the few `find` implementations that support `-regex` use different formats of regexps there).

Standard `find` only supports `-name` and `-path` for matching on file names and it's done with basic shell wildcards as opposed to regular expressions but wildcards don't have the equivalent of the `*` regexp operator (0 or more of the preceding atom), its `*` operator is the equivalent of regexp `.*` (0 or more characters), so `Ion_*[3-5]_rawlib.bam` would match on `Ion_9994_rawlib.bam` for instance as `*` matches on `999`.

In this simple case however, you could do it using several patterns and negation such as:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name 'Ion_*[345]_rawlib.bam' \
              ! -name 'Ion_*[!0]*?_rawlib.bam'
```

Non-recursively:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune \
    -name 'Ion_*[345]_rawlib.bam' \
  ! -name 'Ion_*[!0]*?_rawlib.bam'
```

To find files that contain decimal representations of integer numbers `x` to `y` anywhere in the name, you need a pattern that matches that range (like `zsh`'s `<x-y>`) but also make sure that pattern is not surround by other digits. For instance `foo305.txt` does contain `3`, `05` and `5`, all of which match `<3-5>`.

In `zsh`, that would be:

```
print -rC1 -- (|*[^0-9])<3-5>(|[^0-9]*)
```

That is `<3-5>` (which matches, 3, 03, 003...) following either nothing or a string ending in a non-digit and followed by either nothing or a string starting with a non-digit.

With BSD `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find -E . -regex '.*/([^/]*[^0-9])?0*[3-5]([^0-9][^/]*)?'
```

With GNU `find`, same, but replace `-E .` with `. -regextype posix-extended`.

With busybox `find` (though depends on how it was compiled):

```
busybox find . -regex '.*/\([^/]*[^0-9]\)\?0*[3-5]\([^0-9][^/]*\)\?'
```

Another approach is to use `find` to report the list of files, but use more advanced languages like `perl` to filter that list:

```
find . -print0 | perl -l -0ne '
  if (m{[^/]*\z}) {
    for $n ($& =~ /\d+/g) {
      if ($n >= 3 && $n <= 5) {
        print;
        next LINE;
      }
    }
  }'
```

Here, using `perl` to extract all the sequences of decimal digits from the basename of each file, and outputting the files if at least one of those sequences of digits represent a number in the 3..5 range.

Comment: Hi Stephane, thanks for your very detailled answer, I just have one question, I tried some of your command lines with my Linux Ubuntu none works at my side. Maybe I am doing something wrong :-(

Comment: @user979974, I had a typo in one of the zsh commands, but now that it's fixed, they all work (note that Ubuntu is a GNU system, not a BSD one) in a directory containing the sample file names in your question on Ubuntu for me. In which way does it not work for you?

Comment: for example `find -regextype posix-extended . -regex '.*/([^/]*[^0-9])?0*[3-5]([^0-9][^/]*)?' ` output me `ind: paths must precede expression: .
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: @user979974, that should be `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex...`, check the answer again.

Comment: Note that I believe `zsh` is not installed by default on Ubuntu. You'd need to install it first with something like `sudo apt install zsh zsh-doc`

Comment: Thanks Stephane, you were totally right i didn't type well the command line and zsh wasn't installed too. Just have one question, please, it that possible with the command line `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex` to add filename `Ion_*`

Comment: If you mean you want to find files whose name starts with `Ion_` and contains a decimal number in the range 3..5, then that would be `-regex '.*/Ion_([^/]*[^0-9])?0*[3-5]([^0-9][^/]*)?'` or `zsh`'s `print -rC1 Ion_(|*[^0-9])<3-5>(|[^0-9]*)`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want. Thanks so much for your precious help Stephane